# Gaussian distribution in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, math, gaussian

I have two columns (2x10) of data the first column is the data the second is the errors. I want to generate the gaussian distribution value for each value in first column taking it with corresponding errors. So how can I manage that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
# Your array of data and measurements
measurements = np.ones((10,2))
# 10 values drawn from a Gaussian distribution
measurements[:,1] = np.random.normal(0.0,1.0,size=(10,1))
```

Where `np.random.normal(0.0, 1.0, 1)` draws a single value from a Gaussian distribution with a mean of `0` and a standard deviation of `1.0`. See the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) for more information.

The third argument in my code above, denoted by `size`, gives you the shape of the array of samples you require.

Comment: I just want to know why didn't you take mean of the first column and errors as standard deviation ? Thank you very much

Comment: For the second column to be filled with the errors associated with the measurements in the first column, you would need to use `np.random.uniform()' function individually for each element of the second column.